# how to input data in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have 4 files:train.txt,trainLabel.txt,test.txt,testLabel.txt

**train.txt**

```
1,60,feature_col0,feature_col1,feature_col2,feature_col3,feature_col4,feature_col5,feature_col6,feature_col7,feature_col8,feature_col9,feature_col10,feature_col11,feature_col12,feature_col13,feature_col14,feature_col15,feature_col16,feature_col17,feature_col18,feature_col19,feature_col20,feature_col21,feature_col22,feature_col23,feature_col24,feature_col25,feature_col26,feature_col27,feature_col28,feature_col29,feature_col30,feature_col31,feature_col32,feature_col33,feature_col34,feature_col35,feature_col36,feature_col37,feature_col38,feature_col39,feature_col40,feature_col41,feature_col42,feature_col43,feature_col44,feature_col45,feature_col46,feature_col47,feature_col48,feature_col49,feature_col50,feature_col51,feature_col52,feature_col53,feature_col54,feature_col55,feature_col56,feature_col57,feature_col58,feature_col59
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
```

**trainLabel.txt**

```
1,4,feature_col0,feature_col1,feature_col2,feature_col3
1,1,1,0
```

**test.txt**

```
1,60,feature_col0,feature_col1,feature_col2,feature_col3,feature_col4,feature_col5,feature_col6,feature_col7,feature_col8,feature_col9,feature_col10,feature_col11,feature_col12,feature_col13,feature_col14,feature_col15,feature_col16,feature_col17,feature_col18,feature_col19,feature_col20,feature_col21,feature_col22,feature_col23,feature_col24,feature_col25,feature_col26,feature_col27,feature_col28,feature_col29,feature_col30,feature_col31,feature_col32,feature_col33,feature_col34,feature_col35,feature_col36,feature_col37,feature_col38,feature_col39,feature_col40,feature_col41,feature_col42,feature_col43,feature_col44,feature_col45,feature_col46,feature_col47,feature_col48,feature_col49,feature_col50,feature_col51,feature_col52,feature_col53,feature_col54,feature_col55,feature_col56,feature_col57,feature_col58,feature_col59
0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
```

**testLabel.txt**

```
1,4,feature_col0,feature_col1,feature_col2,feature_col3
1,1,0,0
```

dpNum means feature_col

I want to input some data like train.txt

`[1 ,0..........., 1] # a rank 1 tensor; this is a vector with shape [60]`,

And predict

`[1,0,0,1] # a rank 1 tensor; this is a vector with shape [4]`

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? Does `train.csv` really have 15000 dimensions or did you mean 15000 data points? What is the "target dimension" exactly?

Comment: What is `IRIS_TRAINING` in your code? Can you post a small excerpt from that csv file?

Comment: I generated some fake data, and edited my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn) page:

```
# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=2000)
```

I.e. you can access the targets by calling `training_set.target`, this should give you the label for each data point.

Also, I am not sure if you got confused with some terminology: You say that the training dataset has 15'000 data points, but only 1'000 labels, which (at least for the Iris dataset) does not make much sense as I believe that the whole dataset is labeled. Did you mean to say that you have 15'000 training samples and 1'000 test samples?

So, not sure if all of the following is already clear to you, but if not, hopefully it clears things up for you. Say the Iris dataset looks something like this (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)):

```
Sepal length    Sepal width     Petal length    Petal width     Species
5.1             3.5             1.4             0.2             I. setosa
4.9             3.0             1.4             0.2             I. setosa
4.7             3.2             1.3             0.2             I. setosa
....
5.1             2.5             3.0             1.1             I. versicolor
5.7             2.8             4.1             1.3             I. versicolor
```

Now usually the following terminologies are used:

- Each row in the table is a *data point* or *sample*
- The *dimensionality* of a data point is 4 in this case (the 4 features sepal length, sepal width, petal length and petal width)
- The *label* or *target* is the last column in the above table (`I. setosa` or `I. versicolor`). Usually, labels are encoded somehow, e.g. the label is `0` for `I. setosa` and `1` otherwise as you hint towards in your question. There could be more than just those two possible labels, though. E.g. in the Iris dataset there is usually also a third flower called `I. virginica`.
- The *training* and the *test-set* look exactly the same, except that the test set is usually smaller (and you don't make use of the test set's labels other than to evaluate the score of the final output of your classifier).

Comment: Thank you for your terminologies. In my old question train.txt really have 15000 dimensions, and I want to predict 1000 dimensions result.